# mux nodelets(topic tools)-how to use them?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am trying to use the mux_nodelets using the below launch file

```
   1   <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pcl_manager" args="manager" output="screen" />
   2   <!-- MUX the data onto one topic -->
   3   <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="data_mux" args="load pcl/NodeletMUX pcl_manager" output="screen">
   4     <rosparam>
   5       input_topics: [/camera/points, /camera/state]
   6     </rosparam>
   7   </node>
```

my idea was to mutiplex topics:camera/state and camera/points and read the data_mux output (topic)

but it gives an error as below

```
Client [/image_converter1] wants topic /data_mux/output to have datatype/md5sum [std_msgs/String/992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1], but our version has [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2/1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181]. Dropping connection
```

1. i understand the message type for the mux_nodelet output is PointCloud2 format. how do i change this to a required messsage type ?
2. If i have 2 topics which are having custom message type as input to mux_nodelet. How do i define the the mux_out topic, should i define a message type which is a mix of both the inputs topics ?

PS:the idea of using a nodelet was to save communication time

I am really new to nodelets .Please help .

---

edit : 16 nov

update : I complied the below code snipped below in one of my header files used in a node

```
typedef nodelet::NodeletMUX<camera_test::combine, message_filters::Subscriber<camera_test::combine> > NodeletMUX;
PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS (pcl, NodeletMUX, NodeletMUX, nodelet::Nodelet);
```

combine is message type defined in the package camera_test (combine message time is a custom message with Header)

but when i run the launch file below and run one addition node which publishes topics `/camera/state` and `/camera/points` .

```
<launch>  
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pcl_manager" args="manager" output="screen" />
  <!-- MUX the data onto one topic -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="data_mux" args="load pcl/NodeletMUX pcl_manager" output="screen">
    <rosparam>
      input_topics: [/camera/state, /camera/points]
    </rosparam>
  </node>

</launch>
```

I get the below warning

```
[WARN] [1542361466.932969]: Could not process inbound connection: topic types do not match: [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2] vs. [camera_test/combine]{'topic': '/camera/state', 'tcp_nodelay': '0', 'md5sum': '1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181', 'type': 'sensor_msgs/PointCloud2', 'callerid': '/pcl_manager'}
```

it looks like even after calling the `PLUGLIB _DECLARE` class with new message type,it still expects the message type `PointCloud2` ? and if i do a `rostopic echo data_mux out` ,i get no messages
I don`t understand what i am doing wrong  .could someone please Help ?

---

edit 3 : Below is my header file where i have declared the PLUGINLIB_DECLARE class

can you please suggest what i should change here ?

```
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include <nodelet/nodelet.h>
#include <nodelet_topic_tools/nodelet_mux.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include "camera_test/combine.h"
#include <nodelet_topic_tools/nodelet_demux.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>

typedef nodelet::NodeletMUX<camera_test::combine, message_filters::Subscriber<camera_test::combine> > NodeletMUX;
PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS (pcl, NodeletMUX, NodeletMUX, nodelet::Nodelet);
//typedef nodelet::NodeletDEMUX<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> NodeletDEMUX;
```

btw I have not added an plugin.xml file for this nodelet ? could that be the problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308329/mux-nodelets(topic-tools)-how-to-use-them-?/) by [jithinreju@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37550/jithinreju@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jithinreju@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37550/jithinreju@gmail.com/) on 2018-11-16**:
the mux out still shows PointCloud2
rostopic info /data_mux/output
Type: sensor_msgs/PointCloud2
Publishers:

- /pcl_manager
  Subscribers:
- /image_converter1

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-16**:
Could I please ask you to format your question properly next time? When copy-pasting code or console output (ie: errors/warnings), *always* select the text you just pasted and click the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

**Comment by [jithinreju@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37550/jithinreju@gmail.com/) on 2018-11-16**:
yes,yes . i am sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [nodelet_topic_tools/mux](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet_topic_tools#MUX) documentation:

> To compile the NodeletMUX nodelet in your library, add something like:

> ```
> typedef nodelet::NodeletMUX<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2, message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> > NodeletMUX;
> ```

```
PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS (pcl, NodeletMUX, NodeletMUX, nodelet::Nodelet);
```

So in order to use different message types, you'll have to specialise the template for those message types and essentially create a new variant of `mux`.

---

Edit:

> i had 2 querys ,as per the documentation mux nodelets takes upto 8 topics as input and publishes a combined topic(single) . so does this means the the other nodes publishing these 8 topic should be "nodelets" and not "nodes" ?

if you want to take advantage of zero-copy message exchange, then yes, all topics should be published by nodelets. And they should even be loaded in *the same* `nodelet_manager`.

> Where should I exactly compile the snipped from above ?

In a ROS package. Doesn't really matter which one. As long as the build script is properly configured to allow the compiler access to the required headers.

---

Edit 2: I've not done this myself, but you're probably shadowing the `NodeletMUX` in `pcl` with your own declaration. It could be that by then using `load pcl/NodeletMUX` in your launch file, the `nodelet_manager` is still loading the `pcl/NodeletMUX` version, which only accepts `PointCloud2` messages.

You might want to use a different name for your nodelet.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jithinreju@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37550/jithinreju@gmail.com/) on 2018-11-15**:
i changed the message type and i am able to compile , Do i need to start a nodelet manger seperately?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-15**:
You either need to start a nodelet manager yourself, or reuse the one that you are loading your other nodelets in.

**Comment by [jithinreju@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37550/jithinreju@gmail.com/) on 2018-11-15**:
1)i had 2 querys ,as per the documentation mux nodelets takes upto 8 topics as input and publishes a combined topic(single) . so does this means the the other nodes publishing these 8 topic should be "nodelets" and not "nodes" ?
2)Where should I exactly compile the snipped from above ?

**Comment by [jithinreju@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/37550/jithinreju@gmail.com/) on 2018-11-16**:
edit 2 :I changed the name of the nodelet in the launchfile, still i get the same problem
...
..

<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="newnodelet" args="load pcl/NodeletM
..

is this what you meant whenyou said change the name of the nodelet ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-16**:
You need to change the name of your nodelet in the header where you `PLUGINLIB_DECLARE` it. Changing the `name` attribute of the `node` that loads the nodelet is not going to affect anything.